# D3 change line stroke-width by hovering over legend

Tags: d3.js, hover, line, legend

I made a two-line chart with a legend. I want to highlight the stroke-width of each of the lines to 4px based on the color of the legend circle when the user hovers over it. So, user hovers over the blue legend circle, the blue line stroke-width changes to 4px. Same for the red one if he hovers over the red circle on the legend. Is this possible to do based on my code? Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3-tip.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font: 16px Calibri;
            }

            .line1{
                fill: none;
                stroke: steelblue;
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }

            .line1:hover{
                stroke-width: 3.5px;
            }

            .line2{
                fill: none;
                stroke: red;
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }

            .line2:hover{
                stroke-width: 3.5px;
            }

            .axis path,
            .axis line{
                fill:none;
                stroke: black;
                stroke-width: 1px;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .axis text{
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                stroke: black;
                stroke-width: 0.5px;
            }

            .legend .series {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .legend circle {
                stroke-width: 2px;
            }

            .legend .disabled circle {
                fill-opacity: 0;
            }


        </style>
        <!--...this code will be used on an external html file and instered-->
        <html>
<body>
        <div id="dropdown">
            <select id = "opts">
                <option value = "ds1">Atlas</option>
                <option value = "ds2">BioSQL</option>
                <option value = "ds3">Coppermine</option>
                <option value = "ds4">Ensembl</option>
                <option value = "ds5">Mediawiki</option>
                <option value = "ds6">Opencart</option>
                <option value = "ds7">PhpBB</option>
                <option value = "ds8">Typo3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("worked");
            var ds1="../CSV/atlas/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds2="../CSV/biosql/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds3="../CSV/coppermine/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds4="../CSV/ensembl/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds5="../CSV/mediawiki/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds6="../CSV/opencart/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds7="../CSV/phpbb/results/metrics.csv";
            var ds8="../CSV/typo3/results/metrics.csv";
        </script>
</body>
</html>     <!--...............................................................-->
        <div id="area1"></div>
        <div id="area2"></div>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">



var margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 0, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    height2 = 870 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

var color = d3.scale.category20()
        .range(["#1f77b4", "#d62728", "#98df8a"]);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var x1 = d3.time.scale()
    .nice(d3.time.year)
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var x1Axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x1)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");


var svg1 = d3.select("#area1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height2 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



var line1 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.trID);})
        .y(function (d) {return y(d.newT);})
        .interpolate("basis");

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x1(d.time);})
        .y(function (d) {return y(d.newT);})
        .interpolate("basis");

var dsv = d3.dsv(";", "text/plain");    //setting the delimiter
var dataset = []                        //defining the data array
var datapath="../CSV/atlas/results/metrics.csv";
    dsv(datapath, function(data){   //------------select the file to load the csv------------

        var label = document.getElementById('opts')[document.getElementById('opts').selectedIndex].innerHTML;//takes the name of the f
        console.log(label);

        dataset= data.map(function(d){      //parse
            return {                        //insert parsed data in the array
                trID: +d["trID"],
                newT: +d["#newT"],
                time: +d["time"]            
            };
        });


        dataset.forEach(function(d){
            d.time = new Date(d.time*1000);
        });

        console.log(dataset);
        x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.trID; }));
        x1.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.time; }));
//      y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset.map( function(d) {return d.newT}))]);
        y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.newT; }));

//------------------creating the lines---------------------

        svg1.append("path")
            .datum(dataset)
            .attr("class", "line1")
            .attr("d", line1);

        svg1.append("path")
            .datum(dataset)
            .attr("class", "line2")
//          .style("stroke-dasharray",("5,5"))
            .attr("d", line2);

//----------------appending Legend--------------------------
        var legend = svg1.selectAll(".legend")
            .data((["Duration/Time","Duration/ID"]).slice().reverse())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });


        legend.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 7)
            .attr("cx", 45)
            .attr("cy", 10)
            .style("fill", color);

        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 54)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "begin")
            .style("font-family", "Calibri")
            .text(function(d) { return d; });           
//-----------------------------------------------------------       
        svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("x", width)
            .attr("y", -6)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("trID");

        svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x1 axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2  + ")")
            .call(x1Axis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("x", width)
            .attr("y", -6)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("time");

        svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("num of tables");

        svg1.append("text")
            .attr("class","simpletext")
            .attr("x", (width/2))
            .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top/2))
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "20px")
            .style("text-decoration", "underline")
            .text(label);
    });

    d3.select('#opts')
        .on('change', function(){
            var dataset=[]
            var datapath = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
            label = document.getElementById('opts')[document.getElementById('opts').selectedIndex].innerHTML;


            dsv(datapath, function(data){   //------------select the file to load the csv------------
                dataset= data.map(function(d){      //parse
                    return {                        //insert parsed data in the array
                    trID: +d["trID"],
                    newT: +d["#newT"],
                    time: +d["time"]
                    };
                });

                dataset.forEach(function(d){
                    d.time = new Date(d.time*1000);
                });

            x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.trID; }));
            x1.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.time; }));
//          y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset.map( function(d) {return d.newT}))]);
            y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.newT; }));           

            d3.selectAll(".line1")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("d", line1(dataset));

            d3.selectAll(".line2")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("d", line2(dataset));

            //Update Axis
            //Update X axis
            svg1.select(".x.axis")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .call(xAxis);

            svg1.select(".x1.axis")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .call(x1Axis);
            //Update Y axis
            svg1.select(".y.axis")
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .call(yAxis);

            svg1.selectAll("path")
                .data(dataset)
                .exit()
                .remove();
                console.log(label);

            svg1.selectAll(".simpletext")
                .transition()
                .text(label);
/*          .attr("x", (width/2))
            .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top/2))
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "20px")
            .style("text-decoration", "underline")
            .text(label);*/
        });
    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I define my color as this:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20()
            .range(["#1f77b4", "#d62728", "#98df8a"]);
```

And each of my lines as this:

```
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.trID);})
        .y(function (d) {return y(d.newT);})
        .interpolate("basis");

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x1(d.time);})
        .y(function (d) {return y(d.newT);})
        .interpolate("basis");
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible.

So first it has nothing to do with `line1` and `line2` - they are about data of the line, not actual visual element. You need to change style of the `path` elements `.line1` and `.line2`.

You can add event listeners when creating the legend.

```
//----------------appending Legend--------------------------
var legend = svg1.selectAll(".legend")
    .data((["Duration/Time","Duration/ID"]).slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        if (d === "Duration/ID") {
            // line1's legend is hovered
            svg1.selectAll(".line1").style("stroke-width", "4px");
        }
        else if (d === "Duration/Time") {
            // line2's legend is hovered
            svg1.selectAll(".line2").style("stroke-width", "4px");
        }
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        // revert the styles
        svg1.selectAll(".line1").style("stroke-width", "2px");
        svg1.selectAll(".line2").style("stroke-width", "2px");            
    });
```

This is just a demonstration. Of course it would be more consistent to define the styles in css and change class on events, and you may not want to hardcode legend names when you have more/dynamic series.